# Chain of Responsibility vs Interceptor

Tags: design-patterns, chain-of-responsibility

Every request is sent through interceptors defined in a group similar to classes created as chain for passing through. How different is the Interceptors vs Chain of Responsibility?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An interceptor is generally one link in a chain of responsibility, processing messages,
requests, and replies as they move up and down the chain. Interceptors can examine, modify, and augment each message, and thus influence the message data or destination.

http://steve.vinoski.net/pdf/IEEE-Chain_of_Responsibility.pdf